# Join two objects with perfect edge-flow at any stage of modelling?

Tags: modeling

"These are two separate objects. Now, I want to join them in a manner that enables a smooth transition between them (using bevel and subsurf). How can I achieve this without having to start from scratch and without extensive pre-planning?"
[image]

EDIT:-
THIS IS WHAT I COULD DO AT BEST. IS THERE A BETTER SOLUTION OR TOPOLOGY?
[image]

EDIT 2:-
THERE ARE DISTORTIONS IN THE REFLECTION/REFRACTION AS SEEN IN THE IMAGE BELOW. IS THIS DUE TO TOPLOGY AND WHAT WOULD BE THE FIX TO IT?
[image]

Comment: You can boolean then correct the topology a bit, what difficulty have you met?

Comment: you always have to edit it manually to fuse together nicely. or you can easily just do a remesh.  Quad Remesher is pretty powerful.

Comment: @moonboots Yes, that is the approach I took. However, I find it difficult to match the number of vertices on one shape with that of the other. Additionally, when I add loop cuts (Ctrl+R), it tends to distort the shape by adding extra geometry.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie I gave the Trial version of QuadRemesher a shot, but to be honest, it left me feeling frustrated and disappointed. First and foremost, it came with an exorbitant price tag, which was disheartening. And when I eagerly hoped it would work its magic and create the geometry exactly as I wanted, it let me down. Instead of achieving the smooth and precise results I was aiming for, it decided to add these infuriating non-straight lines on a perfectly flat surface. It was beyond aggravating!

Comment: what you show seems ok, anyway does it give the result you wanted?

Comment: @moonboots There are distortions in the refraction in the glass. Is this due to topology? And is there a fix to it? (Image added to my question above)

Comment: could you please share your file?

Comment: @moonboots yes, but how?

Comment: Use https://blend-exchange.com/ or another platform

Comment: @moonboots [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=BVk6A1VR" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/BVk6A1VR/)

Comment: it looks like it's the reflection that it is supposed to have with this topology, if you want something less round, you probably need to add a support edge loop? https://zupimages.net/up/23/30/rd59.jpg

Comment: @moonboots Indeed, when I introduced an additional edge loop, the reflection exhibited a distinct wave pattern. This behavior seems to be directly influenced by the topology. Furthermore, to address the issue of jaggedness, I increased the subdivision level from 2 to 6. Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Please don't write in all caps in the title or body of any posts, it is the written equivalent of shouting, is [harder to read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Readability) and may be [considered rude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Computing). Please use the [edit] button below the post to change you text into regular case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's caused by your topology, it is round so it makes the reflection look round. Add a support edge loop in order to sharp the bottom edge of your vertical shape:

[image]